# Solspace Calendar & dynamic parameters

Tags: playa, solspace-calendar

Does {exp:calendar:events} accept dynamic parameters?

I am trying to pass this in:

```
calendar_id="{tunnel_calendar}{entry_id}{/tunnel_calendar}"
```

where {tunnel_calendar} is a PLAYA field but this isn't being parsed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Turn on Template Debugging in EE**. This will allow you to see if tags are parsed correctly and in the right order.

In the Template Debugger, if you see the following, eg:

```
calendar_id="123"
```

...that means that your Playa code parses before `{exp:calendar:events}`, and all is good.

If you see the following, as-is:

```
calendar_id="{tunnel_calendar}{entry_id}{/tunnel_calendar}"
```

...that means that your Playa code **isn't** parsed before `{exp:calendar:events}`, in which case you'll need to rethink your EE parse order strategy (for example, passing the Playa entry_ids in an embed containing your `{exp:calendar:events}` code. Really depends on the context).

**Highly recommended read**: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html